# How do I pin direct dial to main screen

Tags: pin-to-start

I figured how to pin contact to start. However, I want to go further and make it direct dial that person. Right now I have to click on tile and click on phone. How do I make tile to dial directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Natively, 2 taps in the minimum you would need to call up a person as you already know.

Your best bet is to use an app like [WizTiles](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-ca/store/app/wiztiles/54397d90-7f29-46b3-81b9-f78c3fd3b779) which is free and allows you to call one of your contacts with one tap from a tile as per what your are looking for.

Alternatively, tap and hold the Windows key and say "Call {person name}" or more specifically "Call {person name} mobile/office/home".